# Cannot convert Integer to Float in Kotlin, and step counter always at 0

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-sensors

I have been trying to code a step tracker app. When I build the app, it doesn't show any errors but when I run it, it crashes and throws this:

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Float
at com.example.fitnesstracker.MainActivity.loadData(MainActivity.kt:159)
at com.example.fitnesstracker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:48)

I have implemented everything that I need but it won't start.

Here is the code for the saveData() and loadData() where I have the error:

```
private fun saveData() {
        val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
        editor.putFloat("key1", previoustotalSteps)
        editor.apply()
    }

    private fun loadData(){
        val sharedPreferences= getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val savedNumber = sharedPreferences.getFloat("key1", 0f)
        Log.d("MainActivity", "$savedNumber")
        previoustotalSteps = savedNumber
    }
```

These lines are after the setContentView in the onCreate method:

```
loadData()
resetSteps()
sensorManager = getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
```

And these are the other functions that I use:

```
override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent?) {
        if(running){
            val stepstaken = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.steps_taken_id)
            val progressBar = findViewById<CircularProgressBar>(R.id.circularProgressBar)
            totalSteps = event!!.values[0]
            val currentSteps = totalSteps.toInt() - previoustotalSteps.toInt()
            stepstaken.text = currentSteps.toString()

            progressBar.apply {
                setProgressWithAnimation(currentSteps.toFloat())
            }
        }
    }
    private fun resetSteps(){
        val stepstaken = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.steps_taken_id)

        stepstaken.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Long tap for step reset.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        stepstaken.setOnLongClickListener {
            previoustotalSteps = totalSteps
            stepstaken.text = 0.toString()
            saveData()

            true
        }
    }
```

Also the step counter doesn't work. It stays at 0 no matter how much I move my phone.

Comment: Wild guess, try: val savedNumber = sharedPreferences.getInt("key1", 0).toFloat()

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But now I can't seem to figure out why the step counter doesn't work. Do you have any idea?